# Python Django Дата комментария к статье

Tags: python, django

У меня сделана модель комментария, html-форма добавления комментария к статье.

При добавлении комментария не отображается правильно дата и время его публикации, вместо нужной даты, просто пишется None. Поле даты коммента:

```
comment_date = models.DateTimeField('время', default = timezone.now, null = True)
```

Я знаю, что это происходит из-за null = True, но без него я получаю ошибку при добавлении комментария. Параметр default не работает, ранее я пробовал различные вариации timezone.now, но к успеху это не привело. Я думал, что дело стоит в миграциях, но нет, я делаю все миграции верно и это не помогает.

Прикладываю полный код:
models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE) # connecting 'Comment model' with 'Article model' by ForeignKey

author_name = models.CharField('имя автора', max_length = 50)
comment_text = models.CharField('текст комментария', max_length = 10000)
comment_date = models.DateTimeField('время', default = timezone.now, null = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.author_name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

Далее views.py:

```
def detail(request, article_id):
try:
    a = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)
except:
    raise Http404('Статья не найдена!')

latest_comments_list = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]

return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', {'article': a, 'latest_comments_list': latest_comments_list})
```

def leave_comment(request, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)
    except:
        raise Http404('Статья не найдена!')

```
a.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST.get('name'), comment_text = request.POST.get('text'), comment_date = request.POST.get('date'))

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('articles:detail', args = (a.id,)))
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
path('<int:article_id>/', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
path('<int:article_id>/leave_comment/', views.leave_comment, name = 'leave_comment')
```

]

И html-код:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} <!-->detail.html<-->

{% block title %}{{article.article_title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

 <h2>{{article.article_title}}</h2>
 <p>{{article.article_text}}</p>
 <em>{{article.pub_date}}</em>

 {% if article.was_published_recently %}
  Новая статья!
 {% endif %}

 <hr>

  {% if latest_comments_list %}
   {% for c in latest_comments_list %}
    <p>
     <strong>{{c.author_name}}</strong>
     <p>{{c.comment_text}}</p>
     <strong>{{c.comment_date}}</strong>
    </p>
   {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
   Комментарии не найдены, станьте первым!
  {% endif %}

 <hr>

 <form action="{% url 'articles:leave_comment' article.id %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <input type="text" required placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name"><br>
  <textarea name="text" required="" placeholder="Текст комментария" cols="30" rows="10"  width="100px" height="50px"></textarea><br>
  <strong name="date"></strong>

  <button type="submit">Оставить комментарий</button>

 </form>



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Что это `default = timezone.now`? Зачем!? Чем не устроило [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)?

Comment: Сейчас попробую поменять

Comment: Изменил на comment_date = models.DateTimeField('время', auto_now_add = True)
При миграции в консоли выдаёт You are trying to change the nullable field 'comment_date' on comment to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)

Comment: Лично я не знаю, как правильно сделать, оно ругается на то, что нет дефолта и нулла

Comment: Цепочкой миграцией такие проблемы решаются - сначала накатываете миграцию без _ограничений_, потом устанавливаете всем записям значения, потом накатываете миграцию с ограничениями. Ну, либо можно просто пересоздать таблицу, если в ней ещё нет важных данных.

Comment: Миграция без ограничений? Это как?

Comment: @Gasplyak , это ошибка из-за того, что у вас уже есть старые данные в этой таблице/колонке. Насколько я понял, это тестовая бд, которая не имеет особой ценности . Выберите разово какое-нибудь дефолтное значение и продолжите миграцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался с проблемой, она заключалась далеко не в миграциях, а в методе создания модели. Мне кстати помог auto_add_now ! =)
Поясню: Проблема заключалась в методе создания самой модели. Я использовал `a.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST.get('name'), comment_text = request.POST.get('text'), comment_date = request.POST.get('date'))`
как оказалось, это не лучшая практика, поэтому стоит использовать более гуманный метод создания модели:

```
Comment.objects.create(
    article=a,
    author_name=request.POST.get('name'),
    comment_text=request.POST.get('text')
)
```

Всем спасибо за помощь, всем благодарен, вопрос закрыт!